# PowerBI show values from two datasets with same filter on both

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have the goal of showing sales compared to a target. For this I have 2 datasets.

One which contains information relating to customers for each month (left dataset), the other which contains information on the targets that each customer must reach in the relevant month and above all for each customer category (right dataset).

I'm stuck on PowerBI because I need to create a table that shows for each category and reference year the sum value from the left table and the target value from the right table. Obviously I need to be able to filter dynamically on all columns of the left table without problems.

I tried to create a bridge dataset but no resolution. All the tests done so far return me the same target value on the left dataset!
How is this issue dealt with in Power BI?

Customer dataset:

| id | month | category | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/06/2023 | shoes | 100000 |
| 2 | 01/06/2023 | tshirts | 20000 |
| 3 | 01/06/2023 | tshirts | 15000 |
| 4 | 01/07/2023 | shoes | 3000 |

Target dataset:

| month | category | sales_target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2023 | shoes | 500000 |
| 01/06/2023 | tshirts | 215000 |
| 01/07/2023 | shoes | 13000 |
| 01/07/2023 | tshirts | 120000 |

Desired result dataset:

| month | category | sales | sales_target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2023 | shoes | 100000 | 500000 |
| 01/06/2023 | tshirts | 35000 | 215000 |
| 01/07/2023 | shoes | 3000 | 13000 |
| 01/07/2023 | tshirts | 0 | 120000 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to them as tables not datasets.

You can create a relationship between the two tables on (month/Category).
One particularity is that Power BI does not support composite keys,so you need to either join the two tables on a single column like a concatenation of time and category.

Or you can create Dimension tables, which would be the recommended approach and connect to the tables. Remember to drag the fields from the dimensions instead of the "Fact" tables

Comment: Could u give me the steps of this case please?

Comment: You can quickly create a date table in DAX with CALENDARAUTO(), the other "dimension" I would Duplicate the queries in Power Query and Remove all other columns and remove duplicates.
After create relationships between the proper fields.